# Issue with Google Query via Power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, odbc

I'm trying to do some dashboards on Power BI, retrieving data from Google Biq Query with SQL requests. Everything was working until today. Now I'm getting this error message:

> DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (100)
> Error interacting with REST API: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery:
> Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?